# hamburger icon rendering as "X" is a few mobile phones otherwise okay on desktop and many other mobile phones. Problem Specifically spotted on Xiaomi

Tags: css, html

The three horizontal lines of the hamburger icon render as "X" on a few mobile phones. In other mobile phones and desktop the hamburger icon renders correctly as three horizontal lines. To be more specific it is on all XIAOMI mobile phones on all browsers.

The `<Head>` code is

```
</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
    <script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
```

And the `<Body>` code is

```
<header class="headerbar">
  <div role="button" on="tap:sidebar1.toggle" tabindex="0" class="hamburger">☰Menu</div>
  <div class="site-name">ABCD</div>
```

I had to insert an ugly text "MENU".

Snapshot attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNTP9.png)

Comment: Assuming, you use fonts for your Icons, you need to ensure they are loaded.

Comment: If fonts were the issue then why would it affect a few devices only (It shd be universal) and why mainly Xiaomi. Fonts are otherwise loading fine even on Xiaomi as far as text is concerned. Moreover this is not about text but about horizontal bars which start appearing as "X" in Xiaomi. I will rephrase my question in next hour or so with some code. I messed up posting the question this time. My apologies. However am unable to post snapshot due to low credits.

Comment: But it is rendering correctly on other android phones. But Thanks will try your fix and revert.

Comment: Code is fine but not for AMP. Kindly see my repeat question. Have shared the codes.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol you're seeing - which looks a bit like an `X` in a box - is the Android symbol for "I can't find this character in my built in fonts."

You need to provide a font - or Icon Font - for that specific character (U+2630).

As for why Xiaomi doesn't support that... It *might* be because ☰ is the Chinese "trigram for heaven" symbol. They might not have included Chinese fonts on a non-Chinese phone.

Comment: +1 nice one, didn't know about the chinese part. We might need to buy a chinese phone to confirm it, but it sounds plausible. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could instead draw the icon with CSS instead of hoping that each client has the font.

```css
.hamburger {
 display: inline-block;
 }

.hamburger span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div role="button" class="hamburger">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're Client doesnt have a certain Font, there are certain ways to fix it:

- Use a font [CDN](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Delivery_Network) *my prefered choice to use Font-Awesome*
- Deliver Font on Request

#### Use a font CDN

As this method is more suitable, as you are not trying to include a random font, but you want to use a font to display Icons. I suggest you to use [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery). It only provides many more fun and free icons to use.

Just include it as descriped in their [start page](https://fontawesome.com/start):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

To use the Hamburger Icon, just do it like this:

```
<header class="headerbar">
  <div role="button" on="tap:sidebar1.toggle" tabindex="0" class="hamburger"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i><span>Menu</span></div>
  <div class="site-name">ABCD</div>
```

The `<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>` Part includes the Icon. The `fa-bars` class is used to reference the specific FontAwesome Icon. For example change it to `fa-caret-down` to see [this icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/caret-down?style=solid).

Note that im not sure, if your `hamburger` css class is needed anymore, as you haven't shared its code yet. Just being said, that this solution will include the icon without any more css.

#### Deliver Font on Request

Just Upload your font to the `wwwroot/font` folder and link it in your css:

```
/*default version*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lovelyFont';
    src: url('fonts/lovely_font.eot'); 
    src: 
        local('Lovely Font'),
        local('Lovely-Font'),
        url('fonts/lovely_font.otf') 
        format('opentype');
}
/*bold version*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lovelyFont';
    src: url('fonts/lovely_font_bold.eot'); 
    src: 
        local('Lovely Font Bold'),
        local('Lovely-Font-Bold'),
        url('fonts/lovely_font_bold.otf') 
        format('opentype');
    font-weight: bold;
}
/*container element*/
div { font-family: 'lovelyFont', sans-serif; }
/*span elements inside the container div*/
span { font-weight: bold; }
```

be sure to check out the [link](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/01/how-to-use-any-font-you-like-with-css3/) for this one.

#### Summary

I'd clearly go with the CDN / FontAwesome Approach, as it provides much more usability. Browse for any Icon you'd like and just easily include it. On the other hand, it also adds a new dependency to your project, which is not alaways a desired choice.

If so use the approach to Deliver your own font. Make sure it contains the Icons you need and you're good to go. This solution would be best to use, if you really needed to provide your very own font. It could also be containing a simplified version of your companys logo or whatever.

I hope this clears things up for you. If you're interested in why your current solution doesn't work have a look at [terence eden's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185289/4099159).

Comment: Thank you very much for all the information. I am begining to understand now. Regards.

Comment: @TrueSeller Youre very welcome. Well, if it helped you, consider leaving some credits :)